# Capturing stream from a cheap Chinese security camera

Tags: networking, wireshark, camera

I have a cheap security camera and by default, I assume, the stream is being sent to some server and then you can watch it on iPad using dedicated App.

It's obviously not ideal and I would like to capture the stream and watch it directly. But the weird thing is that I watched the traffic with WireShark but I can't see any traffic being sent outside the local network. Merely UDP broadcast to 255.255.255.255.

The camera hat port 80 open but when calling the IP with a browser it requires username and password which isn't provided by the manufacturer.

The question is, why I can't see any traffic from it? Any ideas?

Regards,
Radek

Comment: Make and model of the camera?

Comment: Panamalar Bullet 2S

Comment: @Radek Suski I believe the 255.255.255.255 is only for the Local Area Network (LAN) and only Local (your's), should pick up that message. This is a limited broadcast and does not reach every node on the Internet.

Comment: Yeah I know. That's why I find it weird.

Comment: Do you have have the documentation for it? I am reading it, it says it will not run on 5G, but only 2.4Ghz Wifi. Link for your device(PDF) shows how to set it up for your IPhone, etc. http://www.panamalar.net/upload/file/20190805/Panamalar_Bullet_2S_User_Manual.pdf

Comment: @Radek Suski Note, that the password and username it is asking for is for your router's wifi connection.

Comment: *"why I can't see any traffic from it?'* -- You're rather sparse on details on what you have done to configure your camera.  Such IP cameras do not spontaneously stream video on the network without prior setup.  FWIW the "make and model" of the camera is not as salient as the manufacturer of the SoC inside. One such manufacturer is Goke, and SoCs used in many cameras are the GK7101 and GK7102. You are more likely to find hacking info searching for the SoC than the brand name that is printed on the package.

Comment: @sawdust: I followed the manual and so far everything works fine. I can see the video using the dedicated app. I just don't feel very comfortable that the video stream is going through some Chinese server. 
The camera has to stream it somehow but I can't see it in the network traffic which, correctly if I am wrong, I should have to be able

Comment: *"I can't see it in the network traffic which, correctly if I am wrong"* -- You could be wrong. Is your setup capable of capturing such data using Wireshark? I.E. if you try to capture "everything", do you end seeing only packets addressed to your host PC and broadcast packets? Modern wired Ethernet is point-to-point using switches. Many WiFi cards don’t support promiscuous mode. So if you're not a man-in-the-middle, then your PC will never see packets not addressed to your PC. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63538/how-can-i-capture-the-packets-of-a-lan-device-in-wireshark

Comment: Ahhh, got it. It's have been a while since I did it last time. Thanks a lot @sawdust